# Is my "Soul Shriven in Coldharbour" quest in The Elder Scrolls Online stuck?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I have gotten out of the start zone in The Elder Scrolls: Online and have gotten to Stros M'Kai and Betnikh. However the quest "Soul Shriven in Coldharbour" is still in my quest log as not compelted, and has the current objective "Talk to the Prophet". I canot find where this "Prophet" is - selecting the quest shows that the waypoint is always at Gilzir (the NPC you talk to to go from Stros M'Kai to Betnikh and vice versa) which makes me think that the waypoint is not in any of these zones. Was I supposed to complete this quest before I left the starting zone, and it never registered as complete? Will this prevent me from progressing further in the main quest? If so, is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Try to return to the ship/position where you initially spawned. The prophet should still be there and/or reappear once you come close.

If that doesn't work, wait till level 5, which is when he should appear next to you once again once you enter some town or hub.

If that doesn't happen either, contact customer support (F1 or /help). Make sure to ask for help rather than reporting a bug (which you can do as well, but reporting a bug won't get you immediate help).

Answer (score 0):

He should have spawned the moment you went out of that dungeon in that room in the city where you spawn. When you gain level 4, he should spawn again in front of you, enabling you to talk to him again.